# How do I force the "labeled intent" dropdown to accept my preferred intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

On the intents page to the right of each utterance there is a dropdown with the labeled intent for the utterance.  If LUIS does not agree with the labeled intent it will be red.  In several cases LUIS is wrong and I want to force it to accept the intent I want.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is select the correct labeled intent from the drop down. The utterance will then move to that intent. After it has moved, click the 'Train' button in the top right of the window. This will train LUIS to recognize the utterance within the intent you re-categorized it to. At this time, the red border should disappear.

Utterance assigned to the wrong intent:

[image: Wrong intent]

Training button:

[image: Training button]

Utterance now trained:

[image: Trained]

Comment: I understand how to do that if the utterance is assigned to the wrong intent.  My question is about how to force it to understand that it is assigned to the right intent, that is, I want it to be there and LUIS is wrong.